# An alternative to the Logitech F310 with vibration support?

Tags: logitech

I'm looking for a wired Xinput compatible controller that has vibration support and the same layout as the PlayStation. Basically the Logitech F310 with vibration. I know there was an F510 but I can't find it anywhere anymore for a reasonable price so I'm lead to believe that it's already phased out. It would have been the perfect one. I don't want the F710 because I don't want to worry about battery so I'd like if it's wired.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Thrustmaster series of products? They are a known name and have products that have the layout and featureset you want. Not sure which to recommend specifically because I don't have very much experience with standard game controllers. I moved on to the Steam Controller and have been extremely happy with it.

Comment: Is price a concern? You can use an [actual Playstation 4 controller with the PC](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/explore/accessories/dualshock-4-usb-wireless-adaptor/). If a game doesn't support the PS4 controller natively you can still trick Windows into seeing it as an xinput device with third-party software. You can also use a PS3 controller wired with a USB cable that way.

Answer (score 0):

Logitech has a couple of close alternatives:

- [Logitech Wingman RumblePad](https://www.ebay.com/p/Logitech-WingMan-Rumblepad-963233-0403-Gamepad/141274988)
- [Logitech Wingman RumblePad 2](https://www.ebay.com/p/Logitech-RumblePad-2-963326-0914-Gamepad/141191514)